# Как проверить безударную гласную в слове  грядущий?

Tags: орфография

*Нагрянул* и *грядущий* -  однокоренные слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Элен, а Ваш вопрос имеет практический смысл или чисто научный? Если для проверки безударного гласного однокоренным ударным,то грядущий - непроверяемое, словарное,написание традиционно. В таких случаях я говорю "словарное,написание традиционно - написание корня восходит к архаизму "грясти", но и им проверить нельзя, т.к. ударение в нём не на корне:гря-сти́   [http://newikis.com/ru/dictionary_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.html".](http://newikis.com/ru/dictionary_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8F%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8.html) Исторически однокоренные - грянуть, нагрянуть и др.); 
http://rus-lang.isu.ru/about/group/aksenova/state4/
Точно так же,как мы говорим: "корзина - непроверяемое,но исторически восходит к корню глагола-архаизма кОрзать- плести корзины"
Если в упражнении дано такое слово, значит, можно проверить.Говорим  же мы :Обоняние – -ня- – корень, который мы находим в родственных словах снять, унять, принять.  В слове обаяние, которое происходит от глагола баяти – «красиво говорить, заговаривать»,  -баj- – корень.Вот и здесь мы находим корень Гряд- в слове нагрянуть как остаток древнего глагола грясти.

Comment: Имеет практический смысл. 
Русский язык. П/р Н. А. Герасименко. 2008
Это учебник для СПО. Упражнение 157. Нужно подобрать проверочные слова. Засомневался студент, а за ним и я.

Comment: Отвечаю в ответе на вопрос

Answer (score 2):

По В. И. Далю "нагрянул" и "грядущий" - это родственные слова.

> ***ГРЯСТИ, грянуть***, идти, шествовать, подвигаться, близиться, приходить;
> | однокр. набегать, налетать, наскакивать, накидываться на кого; ударить; в сем ·знач. употр. курск. грякать, грякнуть. *Гром грянул, ударил. Грянем на врага! Грянул дождь, как из ведра. Не гром грянул, что бедняк слово молвил. Грянул сокол на утку. Мастеровой - курица: что грянет (или ступит), то клюнет, выпьет*. Грянуть можно также принять за однокр., гл. греметь. *Песенники грянули*; но вовсе не право относят гл. грянуть к гл. грести: *гребцы грянули веслами*, ударили, налегли на весла, навалились; посему **грянуться**, удариться, грохнуться, упасть со стуком, треском, обрушиться. *Как нагрянули, так и отгрянули*, ни с чем.
> **Грядущий** прич. **грясти**; идущий, ближащийся, наступающий и вообще будущий. *Прошлого поминаем, грядущего чаем*.

Но надо отметить, что связь эта довольно условна, и в современном виде безударная гласная в слове "грядущий" является непроверяемой.

Comment: Если исходить из идентичности корней, то следует признать "горе" и "гора" однокоренными.

Comment: > то следует признать "горе" и "гора" однокоренными.

:-D А это как посмотреть!

Есть старинное слово "горе", означающее "вверх". В современном русском оно почти не употребляется. Где-то у Гоголя я его встречал. А вот в современном хорватском языке это старинное славянское слово сохранилось и широко употребляется.

К тому *"горе"*, которое *несчастье*, думаю, это слово отношения не имеет. А вот к *горам* и *долам*, которые *вершины* и *низины* -- да! Добавлю, что "вниз" по-хорватски - "доли". Стар. русск. "долу".

Answer (score 0):

По сути:

> Нагрянул и грядущий - однокоренные слова?

Да, причем даже не успевшие сильно отойти от исходного значения "наступать, приближаться". Собственно, добавить тут и нечего.

По поводу родства грядА и грядУ. Слова разного происхождения, фонетически сблизились в результате исторических процессов.

По Фасмеру первое - от индоевропейского корня со значением "возвышенность", родственно гре(б)сти, сюда же грудь.  Второе - результат превращения малого юса (носового гласного) в Я. исходно морф означал идти, двигаться, приближаться. Фасмер правда упоминает о версии Педерсона о родственности гряда и гряду, но всерьёз её не рассматривает.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется, что гряда тут за уши притянута. Даже если "зрить в корень".)))

Comment: Цитата из Фасмера :
> Иначе о знач.
см. Перссон (Beitr. 448), который относит
гряда́ к гряду́, ссылаясь на греч. στοχος :
στείχω.